# How to redirect mail from a main inbox to only your smart mailbox?

Tags: mail.app

I have an Apple Mail smart mailbox set up to filter out all of the messages that contain a certain string in the subject line.

Now, the problem is that there are A LOT of these messages and so they clutter up my main inbox. As it stands, I can simply see the messages in the smartbox, but they reside in the main inbox.

Is there anyway I can get these messages to move from my main inbox to the smartbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. Smart mailboxes are basically filters. All mail is still in the original mailbox. Or as Apple puts it:

> A Smart Mailbox shows in one location messages that are stored in other mailboxes. For example, a Smart Mailbox might show all messages from a specific sender or with a certain type of attachment, regardless of the mailbox where they’re stored.
>   [Source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-rules-to-manage-emails-you-receive-mlhlp1017/mac).

You could however create your own sort of smart mailboxes by using rules to move messages around based on certain characteristics. https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-rules-to-manage-emails-you-receive-mlhlp1017/mac.

First create your folders. In this example I created "Today" and "Archive":

[image: Showing folders]

Then go to Settings and create rules.

[image: Settings with Rules]

Example of rules creating a Today folder:
[image: Rule for Today]

This moves all mail of less than a day old to the folder called Today.

[image: Rule for Archive]

The second rule moves all day more than a day old to a folder called archive. This should give you an idea how to work with rules and folders.

Comment: LInk is dead. Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

A smart mailbox is just a virtual mailbox showing mails which match certain rules. This means that you can't physicallye *move* mail into a smart mailbox.

In your case you could create a physical mailbox folder instead and use mail rules to move mail matching the subject string directly into this folder on arrival. Apple has a [support article](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/mlhlp1017/mac) explaining how to use rules which might help here.

Comment: So how do you do that???

Comment: @Ray See update